# Does Growth Details available in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am migrating my application from Fabric to Firebase. I couldn't see the **Growth** tab in Firebase. I want to check my daily new installed user count. Does this data is available in Firebase?

**Fabric Menu**

[image: Growth Tab in Fabric]

**Firebase Menu**

[image: Firebase Menu]

Comment: Can you please provide a screen shot?

Comment: If you're currently using Crashlytics via Fabric, then data will flow there. If you're using Firebase Crashlytics, then data would show up there. @SunSun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase doesn't show you new installed user count. It can show you (using Analytics) the users fidelity, so, you can see how many user open your app daily, or many other features regarding users information (like gender, age, etc).

If you need to know how much daily installations you have, you must publish the app on GooglePlay/AppStore and see them in the relative console.